# python logging with custom handler for Azure Blob Storage on the root logger

Tags: python, logging, azure-blob-storage

I'm having a problem adding a custom logging Handler using an Azure Blob Storage append blob when I try to add this to the root logger.  It works fine if I add this to a separate named app logger instead of the root logger, but then my imported module loggers will not propagate to that application level logger.

Here is my custom logger class inheriting from logging.Handler:

```
class AzureBlobStorageHandler(logging.Handler):
def __init__(self, container_client, path=None):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.path = path
    self.container_client = container_client
    self.blob_client = None
    self.blob_name = None
    self.createBlob()


def createBlob(self):
    # Create a blob client for the log record
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S")
    if self.path:
        self.blob_name  = "{}/{}.log".format(self.path, now)
    else:
        self.blob_name  = "{}.log".format(now)

    self.blob_client = self.container_client.get_blob_client(self.blob_name)
    content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type="text/plain")
    r = self.blob_client.create_append_blob(content_settings)

    
def emit(self, record):
    # Write the log record to the blob
    log_data = self.format(record).encode("utf-8")
    self.blob_client.append_block(log_data)
```

And here is a main application where I try to use this handler:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

import json
import datetime
from os.path import exists as os_path_exists
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, ContentSettings


conf = json.load(open("conf.json", mode="r"))
if os_path_exists("..\conf\conf_global.json"):
    conf2 = json.load(open("..\conf\conf_global.json", mode="r"))
    conf.update(conf2)

#Create an Azure Blob Container Client 
container_client = ContainerClient(
    account_url=conf["persistence"]["AZBlobStore"]["account_url"], 
    container_name=conf["persistence"]["AZBlobStore"]["container_name"],
    credential=conf["persistence"]["AZBlobStore"]["sas_credential"]
)

# Add the Azure Blob Storage handler to the logger
level = logging.INFO

handler = AzureBlobStorageHandler(container_client, path=logging_path)
handler.setLevel(level)

frmt = "%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | in %(name)s | %(message)s\n"
time_format_str = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
formatter = logging.Formatter(frmt, time_format_str)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(level)
```

Before trying to use this logger, the logger.handlers look like this:

> [<AzureBlobStorageHandler (INFO)>]

Then, when I try to write something to the log like this, it gets 'stuck' with my CPU churning away endlessly:

```
logger.info("Job initiated")
```

There is a blob created in Azure Blob Storage, but nothing gets written to it.

After killing that logger.info() call, if I then look at the logger.handlers, I get this error message along with the handler:

> [<AzureBlobStorageHandler (INFO)>]
> ERROR! Session/line number was not
> unique in database. History logging moved to new session 769

If I change my handler classes emit method to include some print statements like this:

```
def emit(self, record):
    # Write the log record to the blob
    print("emit")
    log_data = self.format(record).encode("utf-8")
    print("log_record_created")
    self.blob_client.append_block(log_data)
    print("after calling append_block()")
```

then I can see that I'm stuck in some loop where for one log message the emit method keeps getting called over and over, with a log record being created, but the final print statement after calling blob_client.append_block() is never reached.

Like I said above, this works fine and writes to the log blob as long as I don't try to do this on the root logger.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I ended up adding a print statement to my Handler's emit() method to print the log record on each call.  I noticed that there were a ton of logs at the INFO level from one of the azure library modules that I was using to access the Azure Blob Storage objects.  Here is part of one of those log records showing the logger name and level:

```
<LogRecord: azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy, 20, c:\apps\python310_venvs\base\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\policies\_universal.py, 473, "Request URL: ...
```

Essentially, when I added the Azure Blob Handler to my root level logger, this resulted in new logs being written through my root level logger, not only for my simple log message but for all of these additional logs from the imported Azure module that were propagated up the logger tree, resulting in an endless loop, since I had set my root level logger to "INFO" level.

Solution was to get ahold of this Azure module's logger after importing the module and change its level to "WARNING" like so:

```
logging.getLogger("azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```